# Almond leaves vs banana leaves in an aquarium?

Tags: aquarium, freshwater, betta

I was just wondering - what's the difference between using almond leaves in a tank compared to banana leaves for Bettas? I have seen people commonly use almond leaves in the water for a few days to improve water, etc. But I have also seen people use banana leaves for the same purpose, what's the difference?

Comment: Can you provide links where people tell of this? Or just pages that recommend doing this?

Answer (score 4):

### There doesn't appear to be much of a difference

There seems to be a few reasons you'd want these leaves in your aquarium:

- Lower the pH of your aquarium water
- Releasing tannins into your water to get a more natural brown colour
- Medicinal benefits
- Encourage spawning

Firstly, both leaves (almond leaves and banana leaves) can be linked to reducing the pH of an aquarium's water. In fact, many different leaves will provide this benefit just by being exposed to the water. Indeed, many of the places that tropical fish come from, such as lakes and rivers, will have overhanging trees which will drop leaves into them.

Again, both leaves will naturally colour your water brown (this is one of the key characteristics of 'BlackWater Aquariums') by releasing tannins.

They both have been advertised as having a medicinal benefit to the aquarium by increasing a fish's resistance to pathogens and parasites. For almond leaves I was able to find an [interesting paper<sup>1</sup>](https://wwwlib.teiep.gr/images/stories/acta/Acta%20678/678_25.pdf) on how the extract of an almond leaf, or *Terminalia catappa*, was:

> the most effective in treating *Trichodina* infection

Whilst many sources suggest that banana leaves also possess this benefit, I've had a hard to substantiating these claims.

Finally, both leaves will encourage spawning by their nature but so would many other types of leaves.

I've personally only ever used almond leaves and I can confirm that in my experience they've lowered pH, provided food for bottom feeders and provided hiding places.

#### Summary

It would appear that they share a lot of the same characteristics. Almond leaves seem to be more prolific in fish breeding scenarios and we can say that they do have medicinal properties.

---

1 - "*Antiparasitic, Antibacterial, and Antifungal Activities Derived from a Terminalia catappa Solution against Some Tilapia (Oreochromis niloticus) Pathogens*" - C. Chitmanat, K. Tongdonmuan, P. Khanom, P. Pachontis and W. Nunsong [(link)](https://wwwlib.teiep.gr/images/stories/acta/Acta%20678/678_25.pdf)

Comment: Oh, and also.. is there a certain time period the fish can have the leaves and the tennases they leave in the water for?

Answer (score 0):

http://www.aquariadise.com/indian-almond-leaves/
http://m.bettawan.com/Banana_Leaf.html

I’ve found these articles/ sites among many. It appears that people are using banana leaf only when they cannot get almond leaves.
I have no experience using them, and I’m not a vet so I cannot make a good recommendation.
However, I have axolotls and many people recommend almond leaf for medicinal treatments for fungus and other infections.
I hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks- I just wanted to know, since I had seen people use banana leaves, that I would since I have organic bannana trees that's growing in our yard, and thought I could save some money and use the dried out leaves of that:)

Comment: @user10731 - If you found this answer useful, you can ['up vote'](https://pets.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/vote-up) it so other can see it's useful.